# Zodiac sign component for a React.js astrology project

Tags: react.js, jsx

I'm working on an astrology project, and I have a component for each sign:

```
function Sign({ name, image }) {
  return (
    <div class="tile is-parent">
     <article class="tile is-child box">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src={image} alt="Image"></img>
        </div>
        <p class="title">{name}</p>
        </article>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also have a row that I'm going to repeat s times to create a table of all the signs of the zodiac:

```
import Sign from "./Sign";
import zodiacInfo from "./zodiac";

function getSign(_sign) {
  return zodiacInfo[_sign]["sign"];
}

function getImage(_sign) {
  return zodiacInfo[_sign]["image"];
}

function Row() {
  return (
    <div class="tile is-ancestor">
      <div class="tile is-parent">
        <Sign name={getSign("Ares")} image={getImage("Ares")} />
      </div>

      <div class="tile is-parent">
        <Sign name={getSign("Torus")} image={getImage("Torus")} />
      </div>

      <div class="tile is-parent">
        <Sign name={getSign("Gemini")} image={getImage("Gemini")} />
      </div>

      <div class="tile is-parent">
        <Sign name={getSign("Cancer")} image={getImage("Cancer")} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Row;
```

It feels like I'm being very inefficient.  To make the next two rows, I'm going to have to repeat the row code 2 more times and enter all the sign names by hand.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can put the strings into an array and map through them:

```
import Sign from "./Sign";
import zodiacInfo from "./zodiac";

const names = ["Ares", "Torus", "Gemini", "Cancer"]; // you can add the rest in here

function getSign(_sign) {
  return zodiacInfo[_sign]["sign"];
}

function getImage(_sign) {
  return zodiacInfo[_sign]["image"];
}

function Row() {
  return (
    <div class="tile is-ancestor">
      {names.map(name => (
          <div class="tile is-parent">
              <Sign name={getSign(name)} image={getImage(name)} />
          </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Row;
```